# Display Heading and Description of a HTML template reading from JSON

Tags: html, json

I am working on a simple webpage. I have a following sample json file and an HTML template

data.json

```
{
  "NAME":"SAMPLE_NAME",
  "ADDRESS":"New Brunswick Avenue"
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="address"></div>
```

So i have to display the name and address on the template reading from the json file. Is there any library that i can user for this or any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: So what backend language do you want to use for this? php?

Comment: Are you using any particular javascript library at present?  If so then you will likely find examples of templating for that library.

If not, then you will have to JSON.parse(jsonText) to an object and use javascript to create a dom structure to display the data.

Comment: Currently am not using any backend, its a simple/basic HTML template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a compile-time templating or pre-compiled templating engine sort of thing.
You can build one your own with html, css and using javascript or jquery to change the text of certain elements, but this is going to take a long time if you have big pages.

However there is a library out there that does something like this and its called Handlebars.

Heres a link: http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebarsjs-like-a-pro

This might give you an idea of what it does: [What is the difference between handlebar.js and handlebar.runtime.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147161/what-is-the-difference-between-handlebar-js-and-handlebar-runtime-js)

Here is an example using your html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    // Load your html / template into this variable
    var template = '<div class="name">{{name}}</div><div class="address">{{address}}</div>';
    var jsonData = {
      "name":"John",
      "address": "City Street"
    }
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
    // The output html is generated using 
    var html = compiledTemplate(jsonData);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = html;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you would rather write html outside of the javascript variables you could also do it like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="template">
    <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
    <div class="address">{{address}}</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Load your html / template into this variable
    var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
    var jsonData = {
      "name":"John",
      "address": "City Street"
    }
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
    // The output html is generated using 
    var html = compiledTemplate(jsonData);
    document.getElementById('template').innerHTML = html;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need. Thanks!!